# How to fix CiviCRM Hosting Expired Notification

Tags: profile, installation, system-status

I am continuing to get a system status warning that my hosting has expired and I am not sure how to fix this. I have so far tried to pay twice and I have been billed twice by clicking on the link that reads "please renew as possible using this form." [image]I have the CiviSpark subscription and am using the web-based version.

Has anybody else had this issue or had success in solving it?

Comment: Did you try emailing spark@civicrm.org? Or post in the spark channel at https://chat.civicrm.org.

Comment: @demerit I did email spark@civicrm a while back and have not received a response. Good call on the chat.civi - I will post it there as I was not sure if this was the right place to go.

Comment: Fixed - was an error on our end. Thanks for reaching out and sorry for the confusion. (spark@civicrm.org is the best way to contact us, or the chat)

Comment: Can one of you add as an Answer so this kind of gets 'resolved'